# Why doesn't Knockout's click-to-edit work in tables and with multiple values?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've been trying to get Knockout's click-to-edit function in my application. However, it has some really strange behavior when I try and make it work. Specifically, the input doesn't appear when you try to edit on a page with [multiple editable values](http://jsfiddle.net/j4NB4/3/), and all you get with [tables](http://jsfiddle.net/P2jYU/1/) is a single input box, regardless of how many objects are in an array. Why does this happen?

Here's the multiple values code:

HTML:

```
<h1>Job App Tracker</h1>

<div data-bind="foreach: apps">
    <p>
    <b data-bind="visible: !editing(), text: title, click: edit">&nbsp;</b>    
    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="visible: editing, value: title, hasFocus: editing" /> 
    <b data-bind="visible: !editing(), text: description, click: edit">&nbsp;</b>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="visible: editing, value: description, hasFocus: editing" /> 
    <b data-bind="visible: !editing(), text: company, click: edit">&nbsp;</b>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="visible: editing, value: company, hasFocus: editing" /> 
    <b data-bind="visible: !editing(), text: submit_date, click: edit">&nbsp;</b>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="visible: editing, value: submit_date, hasFocus: editing" /> 
    <b data-bind="visible: !editing(), text: link, click: edit">&nbsp;</b>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="visible: editing, value: link, hasFocus: editing" />
    </p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
// Job app object:
function JobApp(title, description, company, submit_date, link) {
    var self = this;

    self.title = ko.observable(title);
    self.description = ko.observable(description);
    self.company = ko.observable(company);
    self.submit_date = ko.observable(submit_date);
    self.link = ko.observable(link);

    self.editing = ko.observable(false);

    self.edit = function () {
        self.editing(true);
    };
}

// Main KO logic:
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.apps = ko.observableArray([new JobApp('Noodle Picker', 'Picks, noodles, and leaves', 'Noodle Pickers, Inc.', '2014-1-25', 'noodlepickers.com'),
    new JobApp('Not A Real Job', 'Not a real job', 'Not A Real Company', '1969-1-1', 'nope.com')]);

}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

And the tables code:

HTML:

```
<h1>Job App Tracker</h1>    
<table>
    <div data-bind="foreach: apps">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <b data-bind="visible: !editing(), text: title, click: edit">&nbsp;</b>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="visible: editing, value: title, hasFocus: editing" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </div>
</table>
```

JS:

```
// Job app object:
function JobApp(title, description, company, submit_date, link) {
    var self = this;

    self.title = ko.observable(title);
    self.description = ko.observable(description);
    self.company = ko.observable(company);
    self.submit_date = ko.observable(submit_date);
    self.link = ko.observable(link);

    self.editing = ko.observable(false);

    self.edit = function () {
        self.editing(true);
    };
}

// Main KO logic:
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.apps = ko.observableArray([new JobApp('Noodle Picker', 'Picks, noodles, and leaves', 'Noodle Pickers, Inc.', '2014-1-25', 'noodlepickers.com'),
    new JobApp('Not A Real Job', 'Not a real job', 'Not A Real Company', '1969-1-1', 'nope.com')]);    
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try a solution like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/eguneys/j4NB4/5/

```
// Editable Text object:
function EditableText(text, editable) {
 var self = this;
 self.text = ko.observable(text);
 self.editing = ko.observable(editable);
}
```

Comment: This works really well! Kind of odd that KO needs this sort of workaround for what seems like a really obvious use case, but oh well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in `hasFocus` binding. When user clicks by text, all inputs shows, and tried to take focus for yourself! I've deleted hasFocus bindings from inputs and  now they are displayed.

I've updated [example](http://jsfiddle.net/j4NB4/4/).

**Update**

I found a solution how to hide inputs. You can use blur js event. When input will lose focus, all edits will be hidden, and all text will be shown:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="visible: editing, value: title, event: {blur: stopEdit}" />
```

[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/j4NB4/6/)

Comment: Right, they're supposed to be invisible by default. It's only once you click on the text that it switches to the input. I'm trying to make them toggle. Setting them all to visible by default isn't what I want to do, and it doesn't display correctly right now anyway.

KO.js has an example of click-to-edit [on their website](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/hasfocus-binding.html) here. I want to do something like this, in table format.

Comment: That causes everything to change to an input form on click, yes, but they never change back. I was hoping to have them change to input while you're editing, but once you click away it takes on a text form again. Look at the [example](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/hasfocus-binding.html) I linked before to see it in action.

Comment: In knockout example only one input, in your example - five. There is no possible hide them by lost focus.